# Need apache to show unix directory

Tags: apache

I have apache running on unixserverA and I wish to view a file on unix [/app1/bea/hello.txt] in browser using this URL `http://unixserverA/sg/hello.txt`

Kindly help what changes I need to make in httpd.conf.

I have included a conf file [bulk.conf] in my httpd.conf and that bulk.conf file has the below entry which does not help.

ScriptAlias /sg/ "/app1/bea/"

Below is the error I see in my browser

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, user@unixserverA and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Error log shows this:

> [Thu Feb 21 04:57:45 2013] [error] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/appl/bea/hello.txt' failed
>   [Thu Feb 21 04:57:45 2013] [error] [client 109.71.70.209] Premature end of script headers: hello.txt

Comment: Why `ScriptAlias`? Do you want to display a static file or to run a script? Whatever, follow the error message recommendation and check the server error log.

Comment: I wish to run a script. Error message in the log says ....[Thu Feb 21 04:57:45 2013] [error] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/appl/bea/hello.txt' failed
[Thu Feb 21 04:57:45 2013] [error] [client 109.71.70.209] Premature end of script headers: hello.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) directive you instruct Apache to handle any file within the selected directory as script or executable file. As [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/cgi.html) explains, such script is expected to generate valid output for an HTTP response, including HTTP headers. For instance, there's the `printenv.pl` sample script bundled with Apache:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
##
##  printenv -- demo CGI program which just prints its environment
##

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    $val = $ENV{$var};
    $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
    $val =~ s|"|\\"|g;
    print "${var}=\"${val}\"\n";
}
```

As executable file, you could also run it from a console:

```
./printenv.pl
```

I don't know what `hello.txt` contains but the `*.txt` extension suggests it isn't a program at all. If it *is* a program after all, make sure that:

- It prints at least a `Content-Type` header plus a blank line.
- It has the executable flag: `chmod a+x hello.txt`